# If eigenvalue has $n$ eigenvectors, is the matrix the $0$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\lambda_1$ be an eigenvalue of $A \in \mathbb{R}^{nxn}$, with $n$ eigenvectors, and $\lambda_2$ an eigenvalue of $B \in \mathbb{R}^{nxn}$ with $k \leq n$ eigenvectors.

Prove that $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2$ is an eigenvalue of $A+B$ with $k$ eigenvectors.

I'm thinking that if $\lambda_1$ has $n$ eigenvectors then $\lambda_1 = 0$ and the characteristic polynomial is $\lambda_1^n$. This means $A$ is a nil-potent matrix because by Cayley–Hamilton we get $$P_A(A) = A^n = 0$$

I'm confused to whether or not I can say that $A = 0$ in this case because the nil-potent matrix doesn't have to be $0$, but it seems right here.

Comment: What about the identity matrix?

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan You are right but this makes me more confused. I thought that the number of eigenvectors means that nullity of $A$, is this not the case?

Comment: Not necessarily. Eigenvectors corresponding to the same eigenvalue need not be linearly dependant

Comment: The key phrase is "linearly independent". It seems to be missing. Any non-zero multiple of an eigenvector is an eigenvector of the same eigenvalue.

Comment: @Nix Nullity of $A-\lambda I$, not $A$ itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if $A$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ with $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors, then is is a multiple of the identity. Ideed, these $n$ linearly eigenvectors form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so the matrix in this basis of $A$ is $\lambda I_n$, and $A = \lambda I_n$ because it is invariant under change of basis. Moreover, any non-zero vector will be an eigenvector of $A$.

Thus, $A + B = \lambda I_n + B$ has the same eigenvectors than $B$, because for $v\neq 0$
\begin{align}
\exists a \in \mathbb{R}, Bv = av \iff \exists a \in \mathbb{R}, (\lambda I_n + B)v = (\lambda + a)v
\end{align}

Comment: Could you clarify why any non-zero vector is an eigenvector of $A$?

Comment: Because $Av = \lambda I_n v = \lambda v$ for all vectors

Comment: But why are the n vectors linearly independent? That need not be the case